# Replacing `,\r\n` in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to fix a CSV file that has a trailing `,\r\n` in it. No matter what I do, it simply doesn't do anything.  I tried putting the expression in `[]` which makes it replace every single comma. That implies that the issue is that it can't match the newline character.

I have saved the file with Windows line endings using Sublime Text, and have tried both variations of `\r\n`, `\n\r`, and just `\n`.

```
(Get-Content file.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\,\r\n', [System.Environmen
t]::NewLine } | Set-Content file2.txt
```

I'm using PowerShell version 5.1.15063.413

Comment: `Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.TrimEnd(',') } | Set-Content file2.txt` ? or in short form `gc file.txt | % TrimEnd ',' | sc file2.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell turns out to be quite... *special*.

`Get-Content` by default returns an array of strings. It finds all new line characters and uses them to split the input into said array. Meaning there are no new lines present for the regexp to match.

A slight variation of this command using the `-Raw` parameter fixed my issue.

```powershell
(Get-Content file.txt -Raw).replace(",`r`n", [System.Environment]::NewLine) | Set-Content file2.txt
```

Comment: For people still stuck on PowerShell v2 the `-Raw` parameter is not available. Instead what they can do is read in the array, and re-join it with `(Get-Content file.txt) -join "\`n"`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, **[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) by defaults reads and emits the input file's content *line by line*, with newlines of any flavor - CRLF, LF, CR - *stripped***.

While the behavior may be *unfamiliar*, is *generally helpful* for processing files in the pipeline.

As [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044873/45375) shows, **`-Raw` can be used to read a file *in full*, as a *single, multi-line string* instead - which can offer great *performance benefits***.

To give an example of the ***convenience* that *line-by-line* reading can provide**, combined with the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)'s ability to operate on *each element* of an input *array* (if your file has LF (`\n`) endings and you're selectively looking for rogue CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings preceded by `,`, that won't help, however):

```sh
# Convenient, but can be made faster with -ReadCount 0 - see below.
@(Get-Content file.txt) -replace ',$' | Set-Content file2.txt
```

<sup>Note: `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is used to ensure that the `Get-Content` call also outputs an *array* even if the file happens to have just *one* line.</sup>

Regex anchor `$` matches the end of each input string (line), in effect removing a *trailing `,`* from each line, *where present*.

---

**[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) performance notes**:

As hinted at above, **`-Raw` is by far the fastest** way to **read a text file *in full*** - but by design **as a single, multiline string**.

The default behavior, **line-by-line reading is slow**, not least because **PowerShell decorates *each output line* with metadata<sup>[1]</sup>** (in the case of `-Raw`, given that there's only *one* output string, that happens only *once*).

However, you can **speed things up by reading lines *in batches* - arrays of lines of a given size - using the `-ReadCount` parameter**, in which case only each array, not the individual lines, are decorated. `-ReadCount 0` reads *all* lines, into a single array.

Note:

- **`-ReadCount` changes the streaming behavior *in the pipeline***: Each array is then sent *as a whole* through the pipeline, which **the receiving command needs to be plan for**, typically by performing its own enumeration of the array received, such as with a [`foreach` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach).
- By contrast, using **`-ReadCount 0` in the context of an *expression*** results in *no* behavioral difference, which means that it can be used as a **simple performance optimization that requires no other parts of the expression to accommodate it**; using an expression with a `-replace` operation as an example:

  ```sh
  # Read all lines directly into an array, with -ReadCount 0,
  # instead of more slowly letting PowerShell stream the lines 
  # (emit them one by one) and then collect them in an array for you.
  # The -replace operator then acts on each element of the array.
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 file.txt) -replace ',$'
  ```

<sup>Note: `@(...)` is *not* necessary in this case, because `-ReadCount 0` *always* emits an array, even for single-line files.</sup>

A **better-performing line-by-line-processing alternative** - although it cannot directly be used as part of an *expression* - is to use the **[`-switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) with the `-File` parameter** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915223/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] This metadata is provided in the form of [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) properties, which notably provide information about the line number and the path of the originating file. Pipe a `Get-Content` call to `| Format-List -Force` to see these properties. While this extra information can be helpful, the performance impact of attaching it is noticeable. Given that the information is often *not* needed, having a least an *opt-out* would be helpful: see [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537).</sup>