# Regex to remove enter from line starting with specific character in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have huge csv file with data, and some of lines are incorrect and contains enters. When file is imported into Excel then I need to correct hundreds lines manually. I have regex which is work in Notepad++ and remove enters from line which is not start with specific string in this case ";" However same regex is not working in PowerShell script.

Example of input

```
;BP;7165378;XX_RAW;200SSS952;EU-PL;PL02;PL02;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
15:00:00;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;9444253;;;;;;;;;;;;;"Jhon Name";;;;;;;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;Final Check Approved;;;;;;;;;09.01.2023;;;;;Approve;;;;;;12077;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

How it should look:

```
;BP;7165378;XX_RAW;200SSS952;EU-PL;PL02;PL02;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;15:00:00;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;9444253;;;;;;;;;;;;;"Jhon Name";;;;;;;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;Final Check Approved;;;;;;;;;09.01.2023;;;;;Approve;;;;;;12077;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Code:

```
$content = Get-Content -path "C:\Users\TUF17\Desktop\File\Fix\xx_fix_temp.csv" 
$content -Replace '"\R(?!;)"', ' ' |  Out-File "C:\Users\TUF17\Desktop\File\Fix\xx_noenters.csv"
```

Comment: Did you try `\r?\n(?!;)`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: The regex provided by @Thefourthbird works just fine https://regex101.com/r/jh1DzX/1. You're probably still using single quotes and double quotes as you're doing in `-Replace '"\R(?!;)"'`. Try `-replace '\r?\n(?!;)'`

Comment: You have right, single quotes work, Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with line continuation `\` in your ps script.

I would also suggest adding `-Raw` if you want to get content of file as single string, rather than an array of strings, for easier replacing.

I'm assuming it's a .csv file you are using.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\TUF17\Desktop\File\Fix\xx_fix_temp.csv" -Raw
$content -Replace '(?m)(^[^;].*)\r?\n(?!;)', '$1 ' |  Out-File "C:\Users\TUF17\Desktop\File\Fix\xx_noenters.csv"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, this is example of this issue, now I have two lines but it should be just one line

;BP;7165378;XX_RAW;200SSS952;EU-PL;PL02;PL02;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; (ENETR is HERE)
15:00:00;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;9444253;;;;;;;;;;;;;"Jhon Name";;;;;;;;;;Jhon Name;;;;;;;;Final Check Approved;;;;;;;;;09.01.2023;;;;;Approve;;;;;;12077;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: I've updated the code with what you want

Comment: `-Raw` is good pointer, but "line continuation ``\`` in your ps script" is confusing here: there's no line _continuation_, only an effective line _break_ (`\r` == CR, presumably) that is in the _input file_, not in the script. Apart from changing ``\R`` to ``\r`` (or perhaps ``\r?\n``), the OP's simple `-replace` operation will do. Note that unless you add `-NoNewFile` to the `Out-File` call, an extra (CRLF) newline will be appended to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the helpful comments on the question:

- In order to **perform replacements *across lines*** of a text file, you need to either **read the file *in full* - with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw`** - or perform *stateful* line-by-line processing, such as with the `-File` parameter of a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement.

  - Note: While you could also do stateful line-by-line processing by combining `Get-Content` (*without* `-Raw`) with a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, such a solution would be much slower - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915223/45375).
- Your **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), `'"\R(?!;)"'`**, has two **problems**:

  - It accidentally uses embedded `"` quoting. **Use *only* `'...'` quoting**. PowerShell has *no* special syntax for regex literals - it simply uses *strings*.
    To avoid confusion with PowerShell's own up-front string interpolation, it is better to use verbatim `'...'` strings rather than expandable (interpolating) `"..."` strings - see the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.
  - **`\R` is an unsupported regex escape sequence**; you presumably meant **`\r`**, i.e. a CR char. (CARRIAGE RETURN, [`U+000D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d))

    - If you instead want to match CRLF, a Windows-format newline *sequence*, use `\r\n`
    - If you want to match LF (LINE FEED, [`U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a))) alone (a Unix-format newline), use `\n`
    - If you want to match *both* newline formats, use `\r?\n`
    - As an aside: While use of CR *alone* is rare in practice, PowerShell treats stand-alone CR characters as newlines as well, which is why `Get-Content` *without* `-Raw`, which reads *line by line* (as you've tried) wouldn't work.

---

**`Get-Content -Raw` solution** (easier and faster than `switch -File`, but requires the whole file to fit into memory twice):

```bash
# Adjust the '\r' part as needed (see above).
(Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $inFile) -replace '\r(?!;)' |
  Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath $outFile
```

Note:

- By not specifying a substitution operand to [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), the command *removes* all newlines not followed by a `;` (`(?!;)`), effectively joining the line that follows the CR *directly* to the previous line, which is the desired behavior based on your sample output.
- For saving *text*, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) is a bit faster than [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) (it'll make no appreciable difference here, given that only a *single*, large string is written).

  - `-NoNewLine` prevents a(n additional) trailing newline from getting appended to the file.
  - `-Encoding utf8` specifies the output character encoding. Note that PowerShell never preserves the *input* character encoding, so unless you use `-Encoding` on *output*, you'll get the respective cmdlet's *default* character encoding, which in *Windows PowerShell* varies from cmdlet to cmdlet; in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, the *consistent* default is now BOM-less UTF-8. Note that in *Windows PowerShell* `-Encoding utf8` always create a file *with* a BOM; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for background information and workarounds.