# Powershell `-replace` regex does not match newline

Tags: html, regex, powershell

I'm trying to cleanup some html files using regexes (yes, I've seen [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/8954291). I'm not looking to generally parse html) and I want to delete all lines that don't contain tags. My script is as follows:

```
Remove-Item $args[1]
$text = (Get-Content -Path $args[0] -Raw)
$text = $text -replace "^\s*\r?\n"
New-Item -Path $args[1] -ItemType File -Force -Value $text
```

There's a bunch of other things that I want to replace, but I'm mostly attempting to fix

I can verify the internal regex works: VSCode (which uses JS Regex as opposed to powershell's .NET regex) correctly matches (and replaces) the lines in question using the provided regex.

I know that [Powershell is Special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044873/8954291), so I've converted the output of `Get-Content` to a raw string with embedded newlines. This has not helped.

I can verify that the other functions (namely `remove-item` and `new-item`) work perfectly fine, and that other regexes work by changing the regex text from `"^\s*\r?\n"` to `"p", "abc"` and seeing that the `p` tags all become `abc` tags.

Furthermore, the regex `\s*\r?\n` works, so it's not that the regex cannot find the newline.

The regex `\A\s*\r?\n` also does not work, implying that it has something to do with how PowerShell finds the start\end of strings.

What's going on?

---

```html
<p>This is some text</p>

(the next line has a bunch of spaces)
               

<p>this is some more text</p>
```

Just as a reference, my regex should (and does) match the second, fourth, and fifth lines of the above example when using VSCode's JS regex engine (PCRE-like, I believe)

Finally, a decompile of the regex:

```
^         from the start of the string
 \s*      match any number of whitespaces
    \r?   possibly followed by a carriage return
       \n then a newline
```

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
$text = (Get-Content -Path $args[0] -Raw)
```

you have line endings inside `$text` and your regular expression can match them.

The `^` anchor may match the start of any line, too, however, there is a special flag to be used:

```
$text = $text -replace '(?m)^\s*\n'
```

The `\s` pattern covers carriage returns, no need to worry about them and use `\r?`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Ryszard Czech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761341/45375) explains the problem with your approach well and offers an effective solution.

In essence, **you're looking to eliminate *empty* or *blank* (all-whitespace) lines from your file**.

A **simpler - albeit slower - solution** is to take advantage of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s default line-by-line streaming, combined with the ability of many PowerShell operators to act on an *array* of inputs, in which case they act as *filters*.

In this case, you can take advantage of the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) (adjust `-Encoding` as needed):

```
@(Get-Content -Path $args[0]) -match '\S' | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $args[1]
```

The above passes all lines from file `$args[0]` that contain at least one *non-whitespace character* (`\S`) through to `Set-Content`, which saves the filtered lines to target file `$args[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is, you don't *actually* have more than one line you can match.

When you converted the file to a string with `-Raw`, you made it a single line. `^` thus will only match the start of the file because that's the only start-of-string identifier that the regex engine can find.

A workaround for this is to match the newline at the end of the previous line OR match the start of the file, then carry this over to your replace, like so:

```
$text = $text -replace "(^|\n)\s*\r?\n","$1"
```