# What is the fastest way to retrieve the header names from csv files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to organize the column names by retrieving the unique header names of the `csv` files.

I used the following the code to retrieve the header names, but this script response is not fast when I have large size or millions of csv files in directories & subdirectories.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "F:\MY_DATA\ASUSH" -Recurse
foreach ($f in $files) {
if ($f -Like "*.csv") {
  echo $f.FullName
  $Data=Get-Content -Path $f.FullName
  echo $Data[0]
}
}
```

What is the fastest way to retrieve the csv file header names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-Content has a -TotalCount parameter that will only read a certain number of lines.

```
$Data = Get-Content -Path $f.Fullname -TotalCount 1
```

That should speed things up.

Comment: Nice. To complement, if one wants to get the names of the headers as an array: `($Data, $Data | ConvertFrom-Csv).PSObject.Properties.Name`. One might be tempted to use a simple `$Data -split ','` instead, but this would be less robust as CSV fields could be quoted and contain embedded `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that direct use of .NET APIs can also be used to speed up enumeration of files, here's an efficient **.NET API solution** for reading the first line of each CSV file:

```
foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem F:\MY_DATA\ASUSH -Filter *.csv -Recurse) {
  $f.FullName
  # Read and output the first line of the file at hand.
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Take(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($f.FullName),
    1
  )
}
```

Perhaps surprisingly, this is **noticeably faster than the more concise, conceptually more direct solution in [James Parr's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225847/45375)**.

Even a hybrid approach, 
`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines($f.FullName) | Select-Object -First 1`
performs better in my informal tests (but is slower than the cmdlet-less solution at the top).

All these solutions benefit from reading the file's lines *one by one*, *on demand*. That is, processing stops once the first line has been read (unlike your approach, which in essence is `(Get-Content -Path $f.FullName)[0]`, which reads *all* lines into an array first, then extracts the first array element).

The reason that a [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) solution optimized with `-TotalCount 1` (aka `-First 1` aka `-Head 1`) is slower than an optimized .NET API solution is likely due to the fact that `Get-Content` decorates each output line with metadata, as discussed in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761493/45375), which also contains general `Get-Content` performance tips.

Comment: Instead of `Select-Object` can you just use the array reference, `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines($f.FullName)[0]`  not sure if you'd have to wrap that in an array subexpression.  Moreover, there are certainly times when `Select-Object` works more reliably.  However, if we're confident in the files... Something like: `@( [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( $File ) )[0]` seemed to work in casual testing.

Comment: @Steven, for performance it is crucial to avoid index operations here (which don't work on `IEnumerable` instances anyway). `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` is a _lazy_ iterator, and you want to make sure that only _one_ element is read on demand.

Comment: To spell it out: your `@(...)[0]` approach negates the benefits of lazy (on-demand) enumeration, by forcing enumeration of _all_ elements, up front, capturing them in an array that must be created to hold them, and then applying `[0]` to get the first element.

Comment: Apologies I didn't see the Linq portion of your example.  I was only suggesting it instead of `Select-Object`.  In very casual testing the `@(...)[0]` approach seems marginally faster. Taking an average across 10 runs against a rather small CSV file resulted in an average of about 2.5 ms for the array subexpression/index approach and .36 ms for the `Select-Object` approach.  Modest as that might be.  I'd have to test further to see if that changes with larger files.

Comment: @Steven, the point is that for predictable performance you want to avoid enumerating _all_ lines, because with a _large_ files `@(...)[0]` is not only slower than `... | Select-Object -First 1`, it also allocates a lot of unnecessary memory. As an aside: in cases where you _do_ need to read all lines into memory at once, `Get-Content -ReadCount 0` is the fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

Would probably also help if you:

- Use the `-filter` parameter to allow File System Provider to only return .csv file.
- Use `FOrEach-Object` to begin processing before all files are collected
- Eliminate the `$Data` intermediate variable

```
Get-ChildItem "F:\MY_DATA\ASUSH" *.csv -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    echo $_.FullName
    echo (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -TotalCount 1)
}
```