# find string in file from last saved position - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, select-string

I wrote a simple PowerShell script, to find specific string in a given text file, using the **Select-String** cmdlet:

```
$SearchResult = $null

$FilePath = "c:\temp\app\events.log"

$FindString = "error"

$SearchResult = Select-String $FilePath -Pattern $FindString | Select -Last 1



if ($SearchResult -ne $null) {

    Write-Host "The file: ""$FilePath"", contains the string: '$FindString'."

} 
else {

    Write-Host "The file: ""$FilePath"", does not contain the string: '$FindString'."
}
```

While the above snippet is working, it will always return the string found in the file, even if new lines have been written to the target file.

I'm trying to find a way to save the last position/line the script read, and to start from that previous position/line, in the next iteration of the script.

While viewing the **Select-String** man page, I have found the **-Skip** switch, but it's been used with the number of lines to skip, and not the last position/line, to start from.

So, it seems that I need to create a text file, that will hold the last position/line of each iteration using **Out-File**, and to read from it using **Get-Content** in the start of the next iteration, but I'm s not sure how to find the last position/line in each iteration.

In **Select-String**, I can use:

```
$LineNumber = $SearchResult | Select -Expand LineNumber
```

To retrieve the number of the line, but it will work only if the string exists in the text file.

How can I find the last position/line in each iteration, and start from it, in the next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. It uses your Out-File idea and compares the line number you exported to the line number of the recent $SearchResult and if its greater do something and if not, do nothing.

```
$SearchResult = $null

$FilePath = "c:\temp\app\events.log"
$LastLine = "c:\temp\app\LineNumber.txt"

If([System.IO.File]::Exists($LastLine)){

    # The LineNumber.txt file exists.
    $StartLine = Get-Content -Path $LastLine
}
Else {

    # The file does not exist. Assign 0 to the $StartLine variable.
    $StartLine = "0"
}

$FindString = "error"

$SearchResult = Select-String $FilePath -Pattern $FindString | Select -Last 1

if ($SearchResult -ne $null) {

    $LineNumber = $SearchResult.LineNumber

    If($LineNumber -gt $StartLine) {

        # The line number is greatwer than the last occurrence.
        Write-Host "The file: ""$FilePath"", contains the string: '$FindString'."

        # Write write the new LineNumber to file.
        $LineNumber |  Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\app\LineNumber.txt
    }
    Else {
        
        # The line number is not greater.
        Write-Host "There was not a new occurrence of the pattern: $FindString."
    }

} 
else {

    Write-Host "The file: ""$FilePath"", does not contain the string: '$FindString'."
}
```

Comment: @J P, Wouldn't the script miss strings, when there is a gap between each iteration (for example, an interval of 15 minutes between each iteration), in situations when "$LineNumber" is greater than "$StartLine"? as the new line number will override the pervious start line.

Comment: @edwio, if you want to report _all_ matches in the content that was added since the previous run, `Select-String ... | Select -Last 1` is the wrong approach. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: I misspoke earlier: While there's no good reason to represent `$StartLine` _as a string_, the fact that `$LineNumber` - which is guaranteed to be a _number_ - is used as the _LHS_ in the `-gt` operation makes it work as intended. Still, I suggest avoiding potential confusion by ensuring up front that  `$StartLine` is a number as well.

Comment: @mklement0, indeed your right and you could simply ensure the $StartLine is a 32 bit integer by using [int]$StartLine in If([System.IO.File]::Exists() block.

Comment: @edwio My approach was to just to give you a solution based on mostly what you have already done and what you were suggesting to do. I agree with mklement0 and if you want to find all matches then his suggestion is the way to go as my script would need to be completely reworked.

Answer (score 2):

- Indeed, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) doesn't offer specifying a *starting position* within an input file (note that it is [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), not `Select-String` that has a `-Skip` switch).
- Therefore, you'll need to read the input file *line by line* first, and skip the desired number of lines with `Select-Object -Skip`, before piping to `Select-String`.

  - Note that while [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) does read files line by line, in a streaming fashion, it is also painfully slow,<sup>[1]</sup> which is why the [`System.IO.File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) .NET API is used below instead.

Note:

- The following assumes that you want to find *all* matches for your search pattern, either (a) when *first* run, in the *initial content*, or, (b), in *subsequent* runs, in the *content that was added since the previous run*.
  Therefore, `Select -Last 1` is *not* used below.

```bash
# IMPORTANT: Due to use of .NET methods below, be sure to use *full path*.
$FilePath = 'c:\temp\app\events.log'

# Define a path to a file in which the state is recorded after each run.
$stateFilePath = "$HOME\.numberOfLastLineSearched.txt"

# Read the last recorded state, if present.
[int] $numberOfLastLineSearched = 
  (Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $stateFilePath)

$findString = "error"

# Read the file line by line, skipping all previously read lines,
# and search only among the non-skipped ones.
$searchResults = 
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($FilePath) |
  Select-Object -Skip $numberOfLastLineSearched |
  Select-String -Pattern $findString

# The file's current content has been searched in full, 
# whether or not a match was found, so the line after the *last* 
# one is the one to start searching from next time.
# Therefore, save the number of the last line == the count of lines 
# in the state file.
# Note: This solution for counting the number of lines is much faster
#       than (Get-Content $FilePath).Count
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Count([System.IO.File]::ReadLines($FilePath)) > $stateFilePath

# Determine if at least one match was found.
$patternWasFound = [bool] $searchResults

# Print a result status message.
Write-Host @"
The file: "$FilePath", 
searching from line $($numberOfLastLineSearched+1)
$(('DOES NOT', 'DOES')[$patternWasFound]) contain the string: '$findString'$(
  if ($patternWasFound) { ",`nnamely {0} time(s)" -f $searchResults.Count }
).
"@
```

---

<sup>[1] The reason is that it decorates each line emitted with metadata, which hurts performance - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761493/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. may i ask, if the [System.IO.File] is already being used, why not use the File.ReadAllLines method, instead of the File.ReadLines method? or that due to the need of actually reading the file line by line, File.ReadLines is required as the actual iterator?

Comment: @edwio, while you could use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($FilePath)` too, it would read all lines into memory _up front_, and then send them to the pipeline. `::ReadLines()` is the streaming (lazy) alternative. If you're not worried about memory use, you can try `::ReadAllLines()`, but I'm not sure it will actually be faster; however, it does have the advantage of reading the file _as quickly as possible_, which may matter if processes are competing for access to the file.

Comment: P.S., @edwio: A PowerShell alternative to `::ReadAllLines()` that should perform reasonably well is `Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $FilePath`: it reads all lines into a single (`[object[]]`) array up front.